# Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, lit-element, polymer-3.x, lit-html

I am newbie to lit-element, and when use import to include the library, I am getting error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-element".
>   Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Please provide any alternatives/solutions.

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render(){
    return html`
      <div>
        <p>A paragraph</p>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Simple Linux paths as suggested ./ current dir; / root dir; ../ parent dir. From error it looks like it should work with relative path to lit-element in your project or an URL to web source(?).

Comment: It means `'lit-element'` needs to be a relative path eg `'../lit-element'`

Answer (score 22):

This doesn't work because js imports must reference a specific file with either a relative path or an absolute path, assuming your project structure is something like the following:

```
/node_modules
  /lit-element
  /other-library
/src
  /components
    my-element.js
index.html
```

From `my-element.js`, your import would be

```js
import {LitElement, html} from '../../node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js'
```

However, since this kind of configuration is confusing and you'll probably end up setting a build script sometime too, the recommendation would be to keep your imports as they are right now and use a dev server that remaps your imports to `node_modules` like [open-wc's web server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owc-dev-server)

Update (Feb. 2021): The web server mentioned on this question has gone through a few iterations and improvements. The current package is [`@web/dev-server`](https://modern-web.dev/guides/dev-server/getting-started/)

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, this type of import is known as 'bare import':

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
```

And the error happens because web browsers cannot resolve bare imports by themselves.

I don't know what webserver are you using for developing, but a good way of avoid this type of warnings is choose one that could manage this type of imports, for example [web-dev-server](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/overview/.)

There are other approaches, using, for example tools like Webpack, Polymer-cli, Open Web Components, etc, as [this article](https://dplatz.de/blog/2019/es6-bare-imports.html) explains, but, IMO, the [web-dev-server](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/overview/) option is a very good one for start.

Answer (score -1):

1. ```
   import {LitElement, html, css} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/core/lit-core.min.js';
   ```
2. Your files should be in `index.js`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can serve bare module imports with polimer-cli.

a. install it: `npm install --save-dev polymer-cli`

b. Create `polymer.json` in your project with roughly contens:

```
{
    "entrypoint": "index.html",
    "shell": "app.js",
    "npm": true
}
```

c. do `polymer serve`