# TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "remarkable". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript

Have been trying to use the **remarkable.js** within my application without much success.

script.js

```
import { Remarkable } from 'remarkable';
var md = new Remarkable();
```

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

The error is
`TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "remarkable". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507441/relative-references-must-start-with-either-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the cdn script, you can't "import" remarkable, but it will be available globally. You can import it if you use bundler like webpack or rollup.

just do:

```js
var md = new Remarkable();
```