# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "form-data". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node-modules, form-data

I've tried too many things yet couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

Initially, I did get the ' Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". ' error.

I solve that with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56507441/relative-references-must-start-with-either-or)

Then, I did get the same error but instead of axios it was "form-data".

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "form-data". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

But this time I didn't understand where I should change the path. Is there anyone who has run into this problem before?

There are three FormData.js Files and two of them contain like:

```
      import FormData from 'form-data';

      export default FormData;
```

The other is like:

```
       'use strict';

       export default FormData;
```

[Here are my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Ga3.jpg)

[Html File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjLmZ.jpg)

[main index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3uR.jpg)

[module. js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbUIX.jpg)

[FormData.js Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAJcP.jpg)

Comment: You are using `./node_modules/...`; try instead to wrap your application with either webpack or snowpack

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have literally just 3 files as I showed in "Here are my files" link and These files are module.js, index.js, and Html files. The rest of it is the files under the node_modules directory. I just downloaded Axios library, and that's it. I just found some FormData.js files, and I will add photos of them.

Comment: @Hostek I am new at programming what do you mean by "wrap your app with webpack" exactly

Comment: @AlimGölcük Here is a nice youtube tutorial: https://youtu.be/nbwt3A9RzNw

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in the html file. Try change the script module `src` to be `"./index.js"`

Comment: I changed it. Unfortunately not.